# Question marks in Jenkins console output

Tags: jenkins, encoding

I'm running Selenium tests in a Jenkins build.

Some logs in French are part of the output, and `some of zem ave accents`, like `Terminé`

In my IDE, logs are well displayed.

But in Jenkins, `Terminé` shows up as `Termin?`.

How can I fix that?

I tried running my tests with `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you launch Jenkins war w/UTF-8 ?

Comment: I'm not Jenkins' admin but I'll see with them...